# Legal alternative to Kali Linux for forensics

Tags: kali-linux, forensics

I would like to have a bootable USB drive to perform digital forensics (carving, undeleting etc.) in case I accidentally delete files from my personal computer. I know Kali Linux comes with an excellent set of tools, however, in my jurisdiction possession of the penetration testing tools that also come with Kali is legally questionable (read: illegal, unless you are an IT security professional). Are there any good and trustworthy distributions which come with forensics tools such as extundelete, foremost etc., but without the "hacker" software?

Comment: We nearly ended up with such laws in the UK, but we convinced government that if they enacted the laws, then the only people to have/use such software would be criminals. And we would then be at their mercy, as we would not be able to defend our selves.

Comment: Yikes, where is this? Are you _sure_ this is the case, or is this just a scaremongering interpretation of the laws?

Comment: Who will come to know that you have kali in USB and you are using it on your PC? I would worry if it was my company's PC.

Comment: @pipe Germany, § 202c StGB. The law is so vague it even had security experts scratch their heads about the legality of pentesting services. This seems to have been settled by courts, but afaik toolboxes like Kali are still more than questionable for private users ("what use do you have for penetration tools if you are not offering certified legal pentest services?"). Since even Kali's wikipedia page has a section on that, I'm not gonna take my chances.

Comment: A little bit of info. Running `Arch` with `BlackArch` as a repository was fine while I was in one country but I moved to another last Oct and I now need a VPN to update `Blackarch`.... but like @defalt says, no-one checks what's your usb, but getting caught sniffing or doing MITM my be difficult to duck

Answer (score 7):

Kali is a distribution that packages a particular set of tools for a particular set of use-cases. Most, if not all, of its tools are freely available. You might find they would need some tweaking to match any customisations performed by the Kali release team, though.

You might like to start with Debian as a base since that's where Kali has been derived.

Answer (score 3):

SystemRescueCd contains the tools testdisk and photorec which do similar things to the tools you mentioned plus they are up to date. (extundelete and foremost haven't been updated since 2013).

http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/System-tools/

Answer (score 1):

It rather depends on the exact definition of 'legal' wherever you are but for bootable forensic tools I found a distro new to me, [CAINE live](http://www.caine-live.net/page11/page11.html), on a web search.

It looks like a general forensic tool that may suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to get [Archlinux](https://www.archlinux.org/download/).  ISO is lightweight (500 MB) and designed to be fully customizable (the [clean](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Archiso) or [dirty](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Remastering_the_Install_ISO) way).  Then you just install few packages (or whatever you need) :

```
pacman -S --needed foremost testdisk extundelete
pacman -Scc
```

Comment: How does this answer the question about forensic packages?

Comment: How does this do not answer ? He can customize the iso with whatever specific tool he needs. It guarantee no illegal tool is shipped (nothing to search for, there is none), since it is the major concern. Forensic distro often have more tools which are unwanted here. "DIY" is the advice from the top answer, Arch is good at this.

Comment: Arch is good. But so are many other distributions. This seems to be "use Arch because I like it" rather than because Arch has specific support for the unstated set I forensic packages that the OP wants.

Comment: Well, I like it, but I am not alone. It is just an alternative which deserve to be noted, as not only Debian-like users will read this thread. Moreover, this use a well known distro, without third-party, up to date, and do not needs to search and remove illegal tools ! You may not be in its audience, but this answer will please some others.

Comment: It isn't a question about which distributions we may or may not like. It's a question about obtaining software that satisfies legal criteria the OP's country, and on which distributions this software might be included.

Comment: It is related to distributions especially for a DIY answer, as programming questions are related to languages. But I swear, it is not a random "I like Arch, you must use it" but "Do you prefer Arch ? Then it is appropriate and easy to stick with it". We may not agree, but i m tired of this dispute, i stop here.

Answer (score 0):

Try Deft linux (http://www.deftlinux.net/download/). It is focused 100% on forensics, and will have your needed tools included, able to be booted from a USB. Your legal predicament will really complicate things because "hacking/pentesting" and "forensics" tools have much overlap by nature. There should be no reason anywhere that Deft should be illegal (or Kali, for that matter, but I'll bite my tongue on that issue), because if someone messes something up on their computer (forget a password, remove files, etc.), they should be able to recover from the mistake.

With Deft linux (and really ANY forensic tool worth it's salt), it will have a few different password recovery tools, which could easily be considered penetration testing tools, since they are used (by necessity) in both related disciplines.